# Why my result from FFT which is negative frequencies are different from positive frequencies

Tags: signal-analysis

I am trying to analyze a signal from monkey brain by applying FFT on the signal.
By using **numpy.fft.fft** function to perform Fourier Transform on raw signal, I got the power of frequencies in the bellow figure.

My question is why the power of negative frequencies are different from positive frequencies.

Please help me to give your opinions if you have ideas about it.

Thank for helps.
[image]

Comment: The leftmost bin, is the DC component, that's why...

Comment: The DC component has no "negative frequency" counterpart. 

You could perform an FFT shift so that the negative frequencies would be on the left-hand side of the plot and the DC component right in the middle.

Comment: Is your input array real or complex?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis they are real numbers

Comment: Thank you @Ben
So is it your mean?
[link] https://imgur.com/lZ3Sa29

Comment: Yes, the DC bin corresponds to the mean.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much.